# How to save nested class in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 classes in my ruby app.

```
   class EmployeeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
         belongs_to :ContactDetails  
   end

   class ContactDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :communicationAddress, :class_name=>'Address'
      belongs_to :permanentAddress, :class_name=>'Address'
   end

   class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :city, :country, :pin, :state, :street
   end
```

My requirement is to create view for EmployeeDetail and to save communicationAddress and permanentAddress from the same page.

can anyone please tell me what should be the possible structure of _form.html.erb for EmployeeDetail, and what modification i have to make in controller to save address.

thnks

Answer (score 0):

You should try [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [autosave association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) functionality.

But first of all, fix names for association :ContactDetails may lead to very weird errors as Ruby counts all words starting with capital letter as constants.

Preferred way is to use :contact_details and :communication_address style, but :contactDetails should work too

Also, it's preferrable to use singular name for model.

Then in your `EmployeeDetail` model write:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_details
```

It will allow model to accepts contact_details attributes in `contact_details_attributes` field

In `ContactDetails`:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :communication_address, :permanent_address
```

After that you may use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper to create form, something like:

```
 <%= form_for :employee_detail do |employee_form| %>
    <%= employee_for.fields_for :contact_detail do |contact_fields| %>
       <%= contact_fields.fields.for :communication_address do |comm_address_fields| %>
```

You may see some examples: [here](http://rubysource.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/), [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and many others, google by `rails nested form`

Comment: I got it. but when i go to edit page, address fields are not getting populated with the values. I dnt know why?